# How do I get a value from an array session with multiple values to another page on a button click?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am working on a list. The list is displaying all the records from the database into a form.

The form: for each entry on the page1:

```
session_start()   
$_SESSION['incomingMember'] = $memberID;
$arr_nanes = array($memberID);
$_SESSION['names'] = $arr_nanes;
$arr_nanes = $_SESSION['names']; 
foreach ($arr_nanes as $key => $value) {
   $_SESSION['values'] = $value;
   $value = $_SESSION['values']; 
   echo '<form action="../inc/prog/manage-group.php" method="post"">';
   echo '<button name="acceptGroup" value="'.$value.'">accept</button>';
   echo '<button name="declineGroup" value="'.$value.'">decline</button>';
   echo '</form>';
}
```

When I click on a button (accept or decline) then I want to send a particular `$value` to the page 2 with the session.

My issue is that it's only show a particular value on the page 2 even tho I click on another button which has a different value.

I tried this on page 2:

```
session_start();
echo $key[$_SESSION['names']];
```

Also tried:

```
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION['names'] as $key => $value) {
    $value = $_SESSION['names'];
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you really understand sessions.  What goal are you ultimately trying to achieve?  What is the current result of your code?  What is the desired result?  Provide sample inputs, current outputs, and expected outputs.

Comment: There's plenty of issues here. First you set `$arr_nanes`, then you store that value in a session. Then you're setting the same variable with the value from the session, which you just populated with that same variable? Also, in your foreach-loop, you're overwriting the session `values` on each iteration, only leaving the contents from the last iteration in that session after the loop.

Comment: @PatrickQ I want to pass all the fetched values from a button to another page (page 2) with session so the values would be protected to being modified on the inspector mod.

Comment: `echo $key[$_SESSION['names']];` - Where does `$key` come from? What does it contain? Also, since `$_SESSION['names']` is an array, you can't use it as an array key.

Comment: @Manto That's not how sessions work.  The button itself doesn't change/set the session value.  The button can submit a value and tell the server-side code to change the session value, but I get the feeling that's not what you're thinking.

Comment: @PatrickQ I mean passing a single value which the button contains from the fetch, not all of them at the same time.

Comment: @PatrickQ How can I protect it from being modified?

Comment: @Manto Protect _what_ from being modified?  Please try to describe in plain English what you are ultimately trying to achieve from beginning to end.

Comment: @PatrickQ I am fetching values into the button value from the database. If I'll click on a particular button with a value, I want to send to another page with session to being protected from being modified on the inspector mod in a browser. I don't know if this helps.